# addEventListerner("click",function) - text will get appended to a div - but this does not work the second time around

Tags: javascript, function, callback, addeventlistener

Onclick dynamically created elements get added to list, but on the second click it does not work.

```js
document.getElementById("add-comment").addEventListener("click",function(){
 createComments();
});


function createComments(){

//append the new edit to comment list
 var storeDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
 var outerDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
 var att = document.createAttribute("class");  
 att.value = "user-avatar-thumbnail left-position";                           
 outerDiv.setAttributeNode(att); 


 var avatarImg = document.createElement("IMG");
 avatarImg.src ="../1.jpg";
 outerDiv.appendChild(avatarImg);
 var attImg = document.createAttribute("class");
 attImg.value = "left-position";                           
 avatarImg.setAttributeNode(attImg);
 
 var altAttr = document.createAttribute("alt");
 altAttr.value = "avatar-thumbnail";
 avatarImg.setAttributeNode(altAttr);
 outerDiv.appendChild(avatarImg);


 var avatarName = document.createElement("H5");
 var avatarNameContent = document.createTextNode("Added newly");
 var attImg = document.createAttribute("class");
 attImg.value = "left-position";     
 avatarName.setAttributeNode(attImg);
 avatarName.appendChild(avatarNameContent);
 outerDiv.appendChild(avatarName);

 var textRegion = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
 var textId = document.createAttribute("id");  
 textId.value = "comment-area";                           
 textRegion.setAttributeNode(textId); 
 outerDiv.appendChild(textRegion);

 var postCommentButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 var postCommentButtonValue = document.createTextNode("Post");
 postCommentButton.appendChild(postCommentButtonValue);
 var createIDPost = document.createAttribute("id");
 createIDPost.value="post-comment";
 postCommentButton.setAttributeNode(createIDPost);
 postCommentButton.appendChild(postCommentButtonValue);

 
 postCommentButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
 var commentsGiven = textRegion.value;
  if (commentsGiven.length < 1){
   alert("please enter your comment");
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("comment-section").appendChild(outerDiv);
   document.getElementById("comment-section").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("enter-comments").style.display = "none"; 
   outerDiv.removeChild(cancelCommentButton);
   outerDiv.removeChild(postCommentButton);
   var commentPara = document.createElement("P");
   commentPara.innerHTML = commentsGiven;
   var attrComment = document.createAttribute("class");
   attrComment.value = "left-position DescriptionExcerpt";
   commentPara.setAttributeNode(attrComment);
   outerDiv.appendChild(commentPara);
   outerDiv.removeChild(textRegion); 
    
  }
 }); 
 
 outerDiv.appendChild(postCommentButton);
 

 var cancelCommentButton = document.createElement("A");
 cancelCommentButton.href = "#";
 var createIDCancel = document.createAttribute("id");
 createIDCancel.value="cancel-comment";
 cancelCommentButton.setAttributeNode(createIDCancel);
 var cancelCommentButtonValue = document.createTextNode("Cancel");
 cancelCommentButton.appendChild(cancelCommentButtonValue);
 outerDiv.appendChild(cancelCommentButton);

 document.getElementById("enter-comments").appendChild(outerDiv);
};
```

```css
#enter-comments, #comment-section {
border: dotted 1px #bfbfbf;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.user-avatar-thumbnail p{
 background-color:#bfbfbf;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="icon-details add-comments clearfix">
    <a href="#" id="add-comment">Add Comment...</a>
   </div>
   <div id="enter-comments">
   </div>
   <div id="comment-section">
            </div>
```

Here when you click the add comment the first time and enter some text in the text box and click on post button, that text will get appended to a div, but this does not work the second time around.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work the second time around"?
As per my understanding, it works totally fine other than that you are not reverting "document.getElementById("enter-comments").style.display = "none";" to display block to make the textfield visible the second time.

Comment: AHH... such a stupid mistake... thank you